# Are questions about how to perform some task on a specific tool on topic?

Tags: discussion, topic-scope

The question below is not related to sound design in general but rather it's about how to accomplish certain task on an specific audio editing tool:

> **How to select all regions above a threshold in Audition Spectral Frequency Display**
>
> Is there a way to select all regions that have a similar or brighter
>   color on the Spectral Frequency Display on Adobe Audition, instead of
>   having to select each individual region with the lazo tool. It would
>   be similar to how the Color Range selection tool works in Photoshop.

Comment: I think in this particular instance it's a case of 'right tool for the job'. You really need to be doing the heavy lifting audio work in a video-capable DAW, not in an audio-capable video suite.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a general sound-design question and is basically a support topic for a specific manufacturers software package - the master source of which is the manufacturers owners or reference manual.

This is most likely a topic for debate on meta. I'm not personally in favour of questions that can simply be answered by consulting with the software or hardware reference manual in question, but there are others that disagree with me.

I don't think it's strictly off-topic according to the stack description.

Comment: I see. Thanks for sharing your thoughts. I think I won't post it just yet then to see what others could think about this question in particular.

Comment: Yeah I agree with that. It's a question about a software feature that's probably non-existent. We would have to search the manual or do other research to answer it ourselves. So by precedence it's likely to be closed on SDSE. The line for me is how easily the answer can be found online or in the manual, and if it can be interpreted fairly easily.